# Raspberry pi model b waveshare spotpear 3.2 inch lcd touchscreen is not working

Tags: raspbian, touchscreen, framebuffer, lcd

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi portable system and I'm using a [waveshare spotpear 3.2 inch TFT LCD touch screen](http://www.circuitbasics.com/setup-lcd-touchscreen-raspberry-pi/); I have followed the instructions on that page. I get the screen to work but not the touch device.

I'm new to this with screens so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What kind of error messages do you get? Did you check any logs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing. I used the supplied image [direct download .7z](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ceUb50sIDnM0hSVDVaU2JVbUk/view?usp=sharing)
and based my project off of that. The image is raspbian and fbtft, after all,

Comment: your link dosent work

Comment: @OleMathiasGullvåg try again; I updated links

Comment: @OleMathiasGullvåg also, http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.2inch_RPi_LCD_(B)

Comment: how do i open the .7z file?

Comment: @ole Winrar, 7zip and maybe winzip

Answer (score 0):

Heres the direct download you need 7 zip to extract it. http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.2inch_RPi_LCD_(B)#Image

Comment: link only answers are undesirable could you please edit your answer so it includes some more detail?